# NerdTree cd vs CD

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

I'm not quite sure of the difference between `cd` and `CD` in NERDTree. It seems to actually cd into a directory I have to do `cdCD`, so for me they are kind of mushed together. From the docs it says:

> CD -- Change the NERDTree root to Vim's current working directory.
>
> cd -- Change the NERDTree root to Vim's current working directory.

What exactly is the difference, and what might be an example of **only** using `cd` or **only** using `CD` ? It seems like an odd conception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, what [NERDTree's help](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/5e77fb2fef6720eabbfe957cf3a47f3f0a218e05/doc/NERDTree.txt#L283,L284) says is:

> `cd`: Change the CWD to the dir of the selected node. |[NERDTree-cd](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/5e77fb2fef6720eabbfe957cf3a47f3f0a218e05/doc/NERDTree.txt#L558)|
>
> `CD`: Change tree root to the CWD. |[NERDTree-CD](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/5e77fb2fef6720eabbfe957cf3a47f3f0a218e05/doc/NERDTree.txt#L566)|

See also the linked `:help NERDTree-cd` and `:help NERDTree-CD`.

In other words, `cd` will change the Vim notion of the current directory, same as the built-in [`:cd`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Acd) command does.

And `CD` will take the current directory from Vim (the one you can change with the `:cd` command) and make that the new root of the NERDTree pane.

So, indeed, using `cdCD` will work to change the NERDTree root, first by hanging Vim's current directory, then asking NERDTree to reflect that newly updated current directory.