# Nerdtree going to specific directory

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

Is it possible to go to a typed-in directory in Nerdtree (when already in it)? The below seems so common to do:

```
$ cd ~/my/directory/here
```

And with my current understanding of NerdTree it requires me to click 100 times to navigate-by-one to every parent or child to get there. Is this possible to do in nerdtree? Additionally, is it possible to toggle to the last-used directory, such as `$ cd -` ?

Comment: You could try vim’s `:cd` command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Vim's built-in [`:cd`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Acd) command to change directory, followed by the NERDTree [`CD`](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/5e77fb2fef6720eabbfe957cf3a47f3f0a218e05/doc/NERDTree.txt#L566) command (note: that's a normal-mode mapping, not an Ex `:` command.)

So start with:

```
:cd ~/my/directory/here
```

(Note that tab completion will work here to complete the directory name.)

Then use `CD` in the NERDTree pane to use the current directory as the new root.

Vim also keeps track of the previous current directory, so you can also use this command to go back.

```
:cd -
```

See also [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25520/18609).